# 2D array having double the expected amount of indexes

Tags: java

I am currently doing some work with a 2D array of objects. The 2D array is initialised as such:

```
Object[][] twoDarray = new Object[3][5];
```

After initialisation, I then populate the array with a nested for loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < twoDarray.length; x++) { 
            for (int y = 0; y < twoDarray[x].length; y++) { 
                twoDarray[x][y] = new Object();
            }
}
```

Now, from my understanding, every index in the array should be populated with an Object. However, when I print the contents of the array out, I get 15 objects and 15 'null' instances. I thought this array would have [3]*[5] indexes. Another weird behaviour that I do not understand is if I run the code:

```
System.out.println(twoDarray[0][4]);
```

it prints one value which is an instance of an object, and another value underneath which is null.
Either something is going wrong, or I just completely misunderstand 2D arrays. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the full code.

Comment: "when I print the contents of the array out, I get 15 objects and 15 'null' instances." Please show the code that does this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's the same as the initialisation for loops but instead of populating each index I just print it

Comment: @pythonoob You need to show it, not describe it. The code you give here [does not do what you say it does](https://replit.com/@codeguru/PitifulFrivolousDeclaration#Main.java). From your description, I can easily write code that behaves correctly. But that won't help you solve the problem with your code because it will be completely different than what you have. Please provide a [mcve] along with the output. This should be code that we can copy/paste and run ourselves and get the same output you do.

Comment: Running the code you provided, I only get one output, which is expected since there is only one call for `System.out.prinln()`.  That means you are not providing everything to reproduce the behavior you describe. https://paiza.io/projects/UkuhJIBgx_07gymEf14D7Q

Comment: @JettoMartínez There isn't really any other code that relates to the array. It's a javafx program, I didn't put that in the tags because I thought this may just be a Java problem.

Comment: Is there any other `System.out.println()` in your code? Not only in the code related to this array, but in all of your codebase.

Comment: @JettoMartínez No, this is the only `System.out.println()` in the codebase

Comment: Then you are either printing it incorrectly or possibly shadowing the array with another declaration and printing that.  In any event, your array is not filled with nulls if assigned as presently shown.

Comment: You need to edit your question and show more details in a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(twoDarray));`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You can verify your 2D array with the following snippet:

```java
for (var x : twoDarray) {
    for (var y : x) {
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Which should give you something similar to this:

```
java.lang.Object@1c655221
java.lang.Object@ee7d9f1
java.lang.Object@15615099
java.lang.Object@1edf1c96
java.lang.Object@368102c8
java.lang.Object@6996db8
java.lang.Object@1963006a
java.lang.Object@7fbe847c
java.lang.Object@41975e01
java.lang.Object@c2e1f26
java.lang.Object@dcf3e99
java.lang.Object@6d9c638
java.lang.Object@7dc5e7b4
java.lang.Object@1ee0005
java.lang.Object@75a1cd57
```

From the sound of it, your problem is elsewhere.